# How can I catch reports from Operators in Python script?

Tags: python, operator

Is it possible to catch reports from Operators in a Python script?

For example, the Operator `bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply()` shows errors in the console when something goes wrong. I'd be happy to have a `try... catch...` method to handle those.

Same with some addons like *3D Print Toolbox* who send back useful info in the console and UI, but I can't seem to find a way to catch those. Is this possible?

**Update**:
To give a concrete example, [this file](https://developer.blender.org/F18159) uses a boolean modifier on two objects and when applied, the Operator returns a lot of `WARNING` or errors in the console. How could I catch those?

Comment: This isn't really a blender question so much as a python question. What you're looking for is error handling in python, and here's the docs about that: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html

Comment: @TLousky Sorry if my question is badly formulated. But Operators can [report](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_76b_release/bpy.types.Operator.html?highlight=bpy.types.operator#bpy.types.Operator.report) data or info or messages when they fail, operate or succeed.  So I'm not maybe going to use `try... catch`, but if I could somehow access those reports, that would be useful.

Comment: OK, if the operator failed but did not trigger an exception that stops the script, you will be able to see the result in the operator's return value: `res = bpy.ops.some_operator()`. Common values are `{'FINISHED'}`, `{'CANCELED'}` and `{'RUNNING_MODAL'}`, among others.

Comment: @TLousky: Ok. Thx. Yes, that works. But I'm not interested in what an operator returns, but at the calls to the `report()` function from those Operators. For a particular and specific example, in the *3D Print Toolbox* addon, at [line 477](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/BA/browse/master/object_print3d_utils/operators.py;7d832c33d5cf1632823ebfc673c9d74343e8fb3b$477), the `Operator.report()` function is called. That's what I'm trying to catch.

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18874/return-values-of-higher-ui-functions

Comment: Also related to http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/26098/python-modifier-error-handling

Comment: Unfortunately, in that [previous related link](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/26098/python-modifier-error-handling), the `try:... except:...` around the `bpy.ops.modifier_apply()` does not work for me. The error is returned but the except is not called.

Comment: Also related to: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6119/suppress-output-of-python-operators-bpy-ops

Comment: I consider this a mild defect in the architecture of blender's operator mechanism.  You are encouraged to write operators in such a manner that their logic is difficult to reuse.  I once wrote an operator that called a helper function that threw exceptions which were caught by the operator wrapper and turned into report()s.  When I tried to contribute the source code they told me not to use and catch exceptions, thus making my code much clumsier to reuse.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### For Operator Error Reports

Catching Errors is handled separately, this example catches the error report and prints it as a string.

```
import bpy
try:
    bpy.ops.object.vertex_group_add()
except RuntimeError as ex:
    error_report = "\n".join(ex.args)
    print("Caught error:", error_report)
```

### For Operator Info Reports

Python can temporarily redirect the `stdout` using [`contextlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html), this is ideal since you may not want to suppress output for _all_ scripts, just selectively redirect some output.

eg:

```
import bpy

import io
from contextlib import redirect_stdout

stdout = io.StringIO()
with redirect_stdout(stdout):
    bpy.ops.mesh.remove_doubles()
```

If you want you can read the output back out or use it however you like.

```
stdout.seek(0)
output = stdout.read()
print("Report was %r" % output)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a hack I found to solve parts of this problem. It will work with Operators using the [`report()` function](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.Operator.html?highlight=bpy.types.operator#bpy.types.Operator.report) to display data back to the user but don't provide a way to catch that data in other ways.

Those reports are both displayed in the Information window and in the console. So the trick I found is to do temporarily reroute the `stdout` from Python to a text file and re-read the text file afterwards.

```
# Opens a text file to write the reports
def openLogs():
    logfile = open( bpy.path.abspath('//') + "log.txt", "r+")
    # reroute stdout to the logfile
    sys.stdout = logfile
    return logfile

# Reads the file content and closes it
def readAndCloseLogs( logfile ):
    logfile.seek(0)
    logs = logfile.readlines()
    logfile.close()
    # Return stdout to its normal state
    sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__
    return logs

# Then wrap your operator between these two functions
logfile = openLogs()
# bpy.ops... # Put your operator here 
logs = readAndCloseLogs( logfile )

# The logs contains what the Operator has reported
```

Comment: Better to use `contextlib`, otherwise a problem with the script can leave `stdout` set.