# How to get last message in console via Python

Tags: python, scripting

How to making a function that return the last line of string in the console (***Assuming the console is not open***). I'm using blender 3.4 and trying to use the `stdout` method, but it doesn't work, is there another way to achieve

[image]

[How can I catch reports from Operators in Python script?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/44993/how-can-i-catch-reports-from-operators-in-python-script)

My situation is assuming I have a handler running in the background. It runs on every redraw in my add-on. When the user triggers any condition in the interface to display any text in the console, then assign the string to a global variable for me to access in some special cases.

For example, When the value of Rest Source changes from Original Coords to Bind Coords in Corrective Smooth modifier, the console will print a line: `ERROR (bke.modifier): C:\Users\blender\git\blender-v350\blender.git\source\blender\blenkernel\intern\modifier.cc:459 BKE_modifier_set_error: Object: "Cube", Modifier: "CorrectiveSmooth", Bind data required`.
Since this triggers redraw, I can put a function into the handler to listen.

[image]

Comment: Do you need the code to be able to retrieve the last line in the stdout stream on your second script run or is it ok if it is in the same script run session?

Comment: I think it's the latter.

Comment: I think it's not possible to read the lines from the system console. you will have to find another way.